Slow function : 504 with Nginx on Plesk
I have a PHP site hosted on a dedicated Plesk.
I have a function that does a lot of things and takes time (processing a lot of data, etc.).
When I run it in the browser I get a 504 Gateway Time-out error
I tried adding additional directives in nginx settings. But I feel like it's not working.
My final URLs look like this:
The 18 is an id and can change
Code:
https://example.org/my/slow/function/18?action=launch
I tried this :
NGINX:
location ~ /my/slow/function/(.*) {
    proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
    proxy_send_timeout 600s;
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
}

I have a 404 page from plesk
Then, i tried this :
NGINX:
location ~ https://example.org/my/slow/function/(.*) {
    proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
    proxy_send_timeout 600s;
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
}


I no longer have a 404, but the instructions don't seem to be taken into account since I still have a 504.
Nevertheless, the operations of my code are carried out well
Any help ?
I tried multiples config..
